# How to add more clearance near the brackets of `blockarray` blocks?

Tags: arrays, blkarray

[image: a]

In the image above, we can see that `blockarray` barely leaves any clearance between the matrix content and the brackets around it. The distance from the first row to the orange line is extremely small. **I would like the edges of the brackets to stretch above and below the contents to leave some extra vertical space so that the matrix looks less crowded.** Something like this (except that the space should be added on top and bottom)

[image]

Also, it is possible to increase horizontal clearance by using a syntax like `>{\medspace}` and `<{\medspace}` in the block preamble, resulting in something like this

[image]

Even though the matrix looks better now, it is still too redundant to specify the amount of space after and before brackets every time in the preamble of the block. **Is there a way to automatically insert that space near the interiors of the brackets?**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{blkarray}


\begin{document}


\begin{blockarray}{r c c c c}

    & A & B & C & D
    \\
    \begin{block}{r [>{\medspace}c c c c<{\medspace}]}  

        A & 245 & 321 & 572 & 214
        \\

        B & 574 & 710 & 230 & 130
        \\

        C & 790 & 211 & 570 & 325
        \\

        D & 621 & 240 & 390 & 170
        \\
    \end{block}

\end{blockarray}


\end{document}
```

Comment: yoy could define a new BA columntype that was `[>{\medspace}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about the vertical clearance?

Comment: you could insert `>{\medspace\rule{0pt}{20pt}` it's a _long_ time since I looked at blockarray internals:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `bigstrut` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{1ex}
\begin{blockarray}{r c c c c}
    & A & B & C & D
    \\
    \begin{block}{r [>{\medspace}c c c c<{\medspace}]}
        A & 245 & 321 & 572 & 214\bigstrut[t]
        \\
        B & 574 & 710 & 230 & 130
        \\
        C & 790 & 211 & 570 & 325
        \\
        D & 621 & 240 & 390 & 170\bigstrut[b]
        \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here another proposal using `kbordermatrix` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}


\begin{document}
\[
\kbordermatrix{
  & \text{\small A} & \text{\small B} & \text{\small C} & \text{\small D} \cr
\text{\small A} & 245 & 321 & 572 & 214 \cr
\text{\small B} & 574 & 710 & 230 & 130 \cr
\text{\small C} & 790 & 211 & 570 & 325 \cr
\text{\small D} & 621 & 240 & 390 & 170 \cr
}
\]

\end{document}
```